# How to Multiply string

Tags: vbscript

How I do this using Vbscript ?

```
s = ("|")*i
y = (".")*(i-j)
Msgbox s & y

==> |||..
```

like in Python.

```
>>> s = ("|")*3
>>> s
'|||'
```

Comment: Hmm. They are variable that I get in script. sorry for not mentioning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [String Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6978d214(v=vs.84).aspx)

```
Dim s : s = String(3,"|")
Dim y : y = String(2,".")
Msgbox s & y
```